# While using ExcelFile() I am getting ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Here is the code i tried. I am trying to read the sheets present inside the excel file and hence tried ExcelFile(), however am not sure why the below error is coming.

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd
# Assign spreadsheet filename: file
xls = pd.read_excel('battledeath.xlsx')
# Load spreadsheet: xls
xls = pd.ExcelFile(pd.read_excel('battledeath.xls'))
```

and am seeing this error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c639baabe58f> in <module>
      7 
      8 # Load spreadsheet: xls
----> 9 xls = pd.ExcelFile(pd.read_excel('battledeath.xls'))
     10 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in __init__(self, io, **kwds)
    374             io = _urlopen(self._io)
    375         elif not isinstance(self.io, (ExcelFile, xlrd.Book)):
--> 376             io, _, _, _ = get_filepath_or_buffer(self._io)
    377 
    378         if engine == 'xlrd' and isinstance(io, xlrd.Book):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode)
    216     if not is_file_like(filepath_or_buffer):
    217         msg = "Invalid file path or buffer object type: {_type}"
--> 218         raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
    219 
    220     return filepath_or_buffer, None, compression, False

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be getting yourself mixed up in the differences between `read_excel` and `ExcelFile`, in summary, one is a function, which incidentally will create an `ExcelFile` instance for you if needed, and the other is a class, but, honestly, you don't really need to worry too much about that.

In summary, the error you are getting is exactly what it says on the tin, `ExcelFile` is confused why you are passing a data frame to its constructor. To fix your problem, simply use

```
xls = pd.read_excel('battledeath.xlsx')
```

and now, `xls` is a dataframe containing your data. Also, just a tip, read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Thanks Danyul. It worked for me. 
Also I think I can simply use this instead,

import pandas as pd


file = 'battledeath.xlsx'


xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)


print(xls.sheet_names)